# Solve equation with logarithm

Tags: analysis, functions

Let $f(x)$ be some distribution function.
Let $a\in \mathbb{R}$ and $b>0$.

Find $a$ and $b$, such that
$$
\ln f(x)=a+bf^{1/2}(x),
$$
in addition, it is known that if $f_*(a,b)$ is a solution for the above equation, then $\int f_*(x)dx=1$.

Thank you.

Comment: For most distribution functions, there are no constants $a,b$ such that $\ln f(x)=a+bf^{1/2}(x)$ for all $x$.  Perhaps you mean: given $a,b$, find $f(x)$

Comment: Thank you. No, the question is find $a,b$. Or at least to show the existence...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose $f(x)$ is the distribution function for the uniform distribution on $[0,1]$, that is: $f(x)=x$ for $0\lt x\lt 1$, $f(x)=0$ for $x \le 0$, $f(x)=1$ for $x \ge 1$.  Show that there are no constants $a,b$ such that
$$
\ln f(x)=a+bf^{1/2}(x)
$$
for all $x$.